# Rails option tags in text_field_tag confusing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I found this code in a github repository, at
 https://github.com/heroku/hstore_example . Many thanks to Richard Schneeman for the only example I've found anywhere that shows syntax, in Railspeak, for accepting user input for hstore data using html.erb. Everybody else just shows how it can be used in the console (I don't think my users will be firing up a command line window any time soon).

I have two questions: 1, why is the word "key" repeated twice in the 5th line? And 2, at the bottom, after the anchor tag, it says herf="#". Is it safe to assume that's a typo, and he meant "href?" The link doesn't lead anywhere, and the class is a JS selector used by the script below the code listed here. Is it misspelled on purpose, to prevent an action?

```
 <%= f.fields_for :data, @product.data do |d| %>
    <% @product.data.try(:each) do |key, value| %>
        <div class="row">
          <p class='span3'>
            <%= text_field_tag key, key, :class => 'text_field dynamicAttributeName' %>
      </p>
       <p class='span3'>
        <%= d.text_field key, :class => 'text_field', :value => value %>
      </p>
      <p class='span1'>
        <a herf='#' class='btn removeRow'>X</a>
      </p>
    </div>
<% end %>
<%- end -%>
```

Also in this app (same repo), we find this code:

```
<%= form_tag hstore_queries_path, :method => :get, :remote => true, :id => 'hstore_query' do %>

<p>Find:</p>
<%= select_tag 'query_type', "<option value='key_eql'>key equal to ?  </option>
                            <option value='key_value_eql'>key equal to value</option>
                            <option value='key_not_value'>key not equal to value</option>
                            <option value='key_like_value'>key like value</option>".html_safe %>

<%= text_field_tag   :key   , nil, :placeholder => 'Key' %>
<%= text_field_tag   :value , nil, :placeholder => 'Value', :class => 'hide' %>

<br />
<%= submit_tag "Run Query", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>

<%- end -%>
```

it's from a partial used to create a search tool for the db. Below the select box code, there's another text_field tag--this time the word :key is expressed as a symbol. I can see that in the upper chunk of code, the key is an iterator variable (though I don't know why it's there twice, and I don't know which of them refers to the iterator). What I don't see, in the lower chunk, is any reference to the model, "products," or database field, "data.
" It's the only hstore in the db table, but wouldn't it at least need to be referenced somewhere? :Key isn't a field in itself, nor is :value--sorry I'm new to this, but how does Rails know what db field is being referred to? It's nowhere in the partial, nor is it passed through the render command that triggers it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1, why is the word "key" repeated twice in the 5th line?

That's passing the value of the variable `key` into the first two parameters of `text_field_tag`.  Those are the `name` and `value` parameters.  The `key` variable is defined on line 2.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag

> 2, at the bottom, after the anchor tag, it says herf="#". Is it safe to assume that's a typo, and he meant "href?"

Yes, that's just a typo.

Comment: Cool, thanks! So now I'm still a tad confused because we have a `name` and a `value` parameter in sequence, with the CSS class after--then in the next field (which stores the `:value` of the key/value pair, the sequence is different, with the CSS class coming before the `:value` assignment. Is Ruby syntax really this loosey-goosey? I'm not sure how the interpreter is able to parse stuff that seems like it's expressed in what looks to be a random order. I also don't understand why the `name`  variable in line 5 ISN'T expressed as `:key`, when that would be more consistent with the line below it

Comment: okay. Line 5 uses text_field_tag, where line 8 uses the iterator from line one ( `d.text_field `), so I suppose the syntax is different for those 2. Also the form itself starts in `new.html.erb` (I've not seen it done that way before) which renders the `_form` partial from there--which is where `f.fields_for` gets its iterator. Weird. I can't see a reason for doing it that way, but perhaps there is. I don't know why `text_field_tag` was necessary in this case either. This code just looks odd to me.

Comment: Further--the `key` variable may be defined on line 2, but the value isn't assigned until it is entered using the input field--there isn't any value to pass until that happens. So why isn't it expressed `:key => key`, the way it's expressed in line 8?

Comment: A lot of this code is based on being able to dynamically add keys and values (based on JS code below the fold). I was just trying to add keys and values, in a form, to an hstore.  I pieced together the answer to that question from a couple of other sources, but Richard's solution still provides greater functionality.